# On iPhone, the uploading restart when I lock the phone

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, progress-bar, dropzone.js, video-upload

I am using the Dropzone.js functionality in one of the projects. where the user is able to upload more than 1 GB of videos to their account. Everything is working fine on all devices excluding the iPhone device Chrome Browser.

When a user is starting the uploading video and between device screen is locked then the video uploading process is restarted and the progress bar is not performing well.

Moreover, when the user refreshes the page at that time we require a popup for the cancel or yes. In all devices we received this kind of popup but not in iPhone devices. Kindly check the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/m-MZak5X4GPi

It would be great if you can provide me the suggestions to resolve these 2 issues.

FYI,
DropeZone Version: 5.7
Technology: Laravel Framework 7.1
PHP Version: 8.0

Thanks

I had tried with multiple parameters of Dropezone but was not able to solve this issue.